# Using jquery to toggle div when parent div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several parent div tags with same class which contain two children divs one of which is hidden. Only one parent is shown at a time.  I have a button which moves through the parent one at a time by show the next and hiding the previous. A second button has to toggle the two children divs of a parent when its visible, it however only works for the first parent and not the others.. pls sample html below.. help is much appreciated.. Thanks

```
<div class="parent"   >
<div id="child1">  text  </div> 
<div id="child2" style="display:none">  text  </div> 
</div>
<div class="parent" style="display:none"  >
<div id="child1">  text  </div> 
<div id="child2" style="display:none">  text  </div> 
</div>
<div class="parent"  style="display:none" >
<div id="child1">  text  </div> 
<div id="child2" style="display:none">  text  </div> 
</div>
```

scripts to move through parent :
    $(function () {

```
$(".parent:first").fadeIn(); // show first step

$("#next-step").val('Continue');
$("#back-step").hide().click(function () {
    var $step = $(".parent:visible"); 
    if ($step.prev().hasClass("parent")) { // is there any previous step?
        $step.hide().prev().fadeIn();  // show it and hide current step
    }
});

$("#next-step").click(function () {
    var $step = $(".parent:visible"); 
    if ($step.next().hasClass("parent")) { 
        $step.hide().next().fadeIn();  
        $("#back-step").show();   // recall to show backStep button 
    }
  else { // this is last step, submit form
        //$("#next-step").hide();
        $("form").submit();
    }

});
```

});

script for button to toggle children for each current visible parent div

```
$('.txtFlip').on('click', function(event) {
 $('.parent:visible > #child1').slideToggle();
 $('.parent:visible > #child2').slideToggle();
});
```

My problem now is the script to toggle child1 and child2 for each current visible parent. It only works for the first parent but not the rest. Help plz...

Thanks......

Comment: share your current script.. if possible a jsfiddle will be great http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The reason it's def. not working is that you have multiple divs with the same ID. IDs are unique, so there can only be one with the same ID.

Comment: Can you please provide your js code please so that I can identify what is the issue

Comment: Dear All, sorry i was away for a while. I still haven't gotten a solution to my pr0blem. I am able move through the parent divs but unable to toggle the child1 and child2 as i move through the different parent divs..  please find a snapsot of my script attached to the above:

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's :visible selector to pick which element is currently visible and toggle based on that.

```
bindLoopThrough = function($button, initial_selector){
    // Define a function that will apply for both sets of buttons,
    // because they have similar functionality
    $button.on("click", function(){
        var $current = $(initial_selector),
            $next = $current.next();
        if($next.length===0){
            $next = $current.siblings().eq(0); // Reached end, get first.
        }
        $current.hide();
        $next.show();
    });
}

bindLoopThrough($("#button1"), ".parent:visible");
bindLoopThrough($("#button2"), ".parent:visible .child:visible");
```